# Pandas dataframe, how can I group by multiple columns and apply sum for specific column and add new count column?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given a dataframe df1 as follows :

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
-------------------------------------
A       1       AA      10      Test1
A       1       AA      5       Test2
A       2       AB      30      Test3
B       4       FF      10      Test4
C       1       HH      4       Test7
C       3       GG      6       Test8
C       3       GG      7       Test9
D       1       AA      4       Test5
D       3       FF      6       Test6
```

- I want to group by Col1, Col2 and Col3 and
- Add new column Count : size of each group
- Add new column Col4_sum : sum of each Col4 in each group

---

**Output need**

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Count   Col4_sum
----------------------------------------
A       1       AA      2       15
A       2       AB      1       30
B       4       FF      1       10
C       1       HH      1       4
C       3       GG      2       13
D       1       AA      1       4
D       3       FF      1       6
```

I try to use

```
df1.groupby(['Col1','Col2','Col3']).size
```

but get only Count column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict of column names and aggregation functions. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
...                    [4, 5, 6],
...                    [7, 8, 9],
...                    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]],
...                   columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> df.agg({'A' : ['sum', 'min'], 'B' : ['min', 'max']})
#         A    B
# max   NaN  8.0
# min   1.0  2.0
# sum  12.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with tuples for specify aggregate function with new columns names:

```
df = (df1.groupby(['Col1','Col2','Col3'])['Col4']
         .agg([('Count','size'), ('Col4_sum','sum')])
         .reset_index())
print (df)
  Col1  Col2 Col3  Count  Col4_sum
0    A     1   AA      2        15
1    A     2   AB      1        30
2    B     4   FF      1        10
3    C     1   HH      1         4
4    C     3   GG      2        13
5    D     1   AA      1         4
6    D     3   FF      1         6
```

In pandas 0.25+ is possible use [`named aggregation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling):

```
df = (df1.groupby(['Col1','Col2','Col3'])
         .agg(Count=('Col5', 'size'), Col4_sum=('Col4', 'sum'))
         .reset_index())
print (df)
  Col1  Col2 Col3  Count  Col4_sum
0    A     1   AA      2        15
1    A     2   AB      1        30
2    B     4   FF      1        10
3    C     1   HH      1         4
4    C     3   GG      2        13
5    D     1   AA      1         4
6    D     3   FF      1         6
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question, how can I apply custom function to the Col4 instead of sum.

Comment: @PaitoonGunhong 0 Then change `'sum'` to `custom_func`

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Col1','Col2','Col3'])['Col4'].agg('sum')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table):

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], values='Col4', aggfunc=['count', 'sum']).reset_index()
df.columns = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Count', 'Col4_sum']
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2 Col3  Count  Col4_sum
0    A     1   AA      2        15
1    A     2   AB      1        30
2    B     4   FF      1        10
3    C     1   HH      1         4
4    C     3   GG      2        13
5    D     1   AA      1         4
6    D     3   FF      1         6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that's a bit more verbose and hasn't been mentioned is to use the [assign function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) as follows :

```
df = df1.assign(Count=df1.groupby(['Col1','Col2','Col3']).Col4.transform('size'))
        .assign(Col4_sum=df1.groupby(['Col1','Col2','Col3']).Col4.transform('sum'))
        .reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

With the agg function and a dictionary, you can customise your output like so

```
df.groupby(['Col1','Col2','Col3']).agg({'Col3': ['count'], 'Col4': ['count','sum']})
```

This should return a group for Col1, Col2, and Col3, while aggregating the count for Col3, and then the count and sum for Col4